# LUA Error: attempt to index a nil value @6:16

Tags: lua, rpc

I am trying to retrieve the Entryhandle UUID by sending a request. However, I am getting this error every time. Can anyone help me solve it or point out where I am making a mistake?

```
local config={}

config.mcast_mac = "00:0a:cd:16:da:f1"


function rpc:epm()                                                                    


 local pkt = CreateFromPath("ethernet/ip/udp/dcerpc/epm")

 --[[data is put here]]


 SendAndWait(pkt, function(res)
local epm = res.get_layer("epm")
--[[data is put here--]]
handle = epm.EntryHandleUUID.to_string()

print("EntryHandleUUID:",handle)

 end



 end,2000)

  return handle

  end
```

Comment: your mistake is that you index a nil value. one of your variables is nil. therefor you cannot access any of its members using the dot operator. don't you have a stack trace with line numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code not valid Lua code. Suppose remove `end` from line after `print`.
To findout where you try get access to nil value you can just add `assert` before each index operation.

```
local config={}

config.mcast_mac = "00:0a:cd:16:da:f1"

assert(rpc, 'rpc is NULL')

function rpc:epm()
  local pkt = CreateFromPath("ethernet/ip/udp/dcerpc/epm")
  --[[data is put here]]
  SendAndWait(pkt, function(res)
    assert(res, 'res is NULL')
    local epm = res.get_layer("epm")
    --[[data is put here--]]
    assert(epm, 'epm is NULL')
    local uuid = epm.EntryHandleUUID
    assert(uuid, 'epm.EntryHandleUUID is NULL')
    handle = uuid.to_string()
    print("EntryHandleUUID:",handle)
  end, 2000)
  return handle
end
```